# Match first letter of a string in Tcl

Tags: string, tcl, match

I want to compare the first letter of a string with a known character. For example, I want to check if the string "example"'s first letter matches with "e" or not. I'm sure there must be a very simple way to do it, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if { [string first e $yourString] == 0 }
  ...
```

Comment: Not an especially efficient solution, as if the string is long and has no `e` in it, you look through it all fruitlessly. `string match` is much better.

Comment: Good point, I must admit it's been 10 years since I touched tcl!

Answer (score 5):

One way is to get the first character with `string index`:

```
if {[string index $yourstring 0] eq "e"} {
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good idea to collect the different methods in a single answer.

Assume

```
set mystring example
set mychar   e
```

The goal is to test whether the first character in `$mystring` is equal to `$mychar`.

My suggestion was (slightly edited):

```
if {[string match $mychar* $mystring]} {
    ...
```

This invocation does a glob-style match, comparing `$mystring` to the character `$mychar` followed by a sequence of zero or more arbitrary characters. Due to shortcuts in the algorithm, the comparison stops after the first character and is quite efficient.

Donal Fellows:

```
if {[string index $mystring 0] eq $mychar} {
    ...
```

This invocation specifically compares a string consisting of the first character in `$mystring` with the string `$mychar`. It uses the efficient `eq` operator rather than the `==` operator, which is the only one available in older versions of Tcl.

Another way to construct a string consisting of the first character in `$mystring` is by invoking `string range $mystring 0 0`.

Mark Kadlec:

```
if {[string first $mychar $mystring] == 0 }
    ...
```

This invocation searches the string `$mystring` for the first occurrence of the character `$mychar`. If it finds any, it returns with the index where the character was found. This index number is then compared to `0`. If they are equal the first character of `$mystring` was `$mychar`.

This solution is rather inefficient in the worst case, where `$mystring` is long and `$mychar` does not occur in it. The command will then examine the whole string even though only the first character is of interest.

One more `string`-based solution:

```
if {[string compare -length 1 $mychar $mystring] == 0} {
    ...
```

This invocation compares the first *n* characters of both strings (*n* being hardcoded to 1 here): if there is a difference the command will return -1 or 1 (depending on alphabetical order), and if they are equal 0 will be returned.

Another solution is to use a regular expression match:

```
if {[regexp -- ^$mychar.* $mystring]} {
    ...
```

This solution is similar to the `string match` solution above, but uses regular expression syntax rather than glob syntax. Don't forget the `^` anchor, otherwise the invocation will return true if `$mychar` occurs anywhere in `$mystring`.

Documentation: [eq and ==](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: what is the efficient way to check if the first character is *, whereas * represents match everything. but I wants to check only if the string starts with * but not any other character.

Answer (score 0):

```
set mychar "e"
if { [string first $mychar $myString] == 0}{
  ....
```